# Using Python COM objects from Excel VBA

Tags: python, excel, vba, python-3.x, anaconda

I am trying to create python classes to be used in Excel, taking references from Python: Programming on Win32.

Currently:
Python script (win32comLibrary.py)

```
class PythonUtilities:
    _public_methods_ = [ "SplitString" ]
    _reg_progid_ = "PythonDemos.Utilities"
    _reg_clsid_ = "{AF272547-D5BC-4452-852E-3F8746672097}"
    def SplitString(self, val, item = None):
        import string
        if item!=None: item = str(item)
        return string.split(str(val), item)

if __name__== "__main__":
    print("Registering COM server...")
    import win32com.server.register
    win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(PythonUtilities)
```

Excel VBA

```
Sub test()
    Set PythonUtils = CreateObject("PythonDemos.Utilities")
    response = PythonUtils.SplitString("Hello From VB", " ")
    For Each Item In response
        MsgBox Item
    Next Item

End Sub
```

Questions:
(a) at the reponse = ... line, there is a `runtime error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Unexpected Python Error: Traceback (most recent call last): File .....`

(b) when i typed `python win32comLibrary.py --unregister` in cmd, it returned `Registering COM server...Traceback (most recent call last): File "win32comLibrary.py", line 19, in (module) import win32com.server.register ImportError: No module named win32com.server.register`

I am currently using anaconda (spyder) and have installed pywin32. Invoking win32com.client methods from Python don't seem to throw any error.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the issue - just to close this off. Not sure if its the difference between older versions of python and 3.x but `string.split(str(val), item)` doesn't seem to work anymore. Instead, I have changed the return statement to `return val.split(item)`. Oversight on my part - apologies.